# Loop to view all dataframes in R

Tags: r, loops

Trying to write a loop to open all data frames in separate windows in R

I have the following code which doesn't work ofcourse:

```
for(i in ls()){
View(i)
}
```

This simply opens up the viewer with i being the name of the data frame.

I have also tried lapply to no avail.

Any tips

Regards

Comment: Provided all the objects in the working environment are (or can be coerced to) data frames, you can do that with `purrr::walk(ls(), View)`

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it only prints again the name of the objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ls()` returns a character vector with the names of the objects in your workspace. 
Let's run this example in a fresh R session:

```
x <- 1:4
y <- data.frame(x = x, y = 2*x)

ls()
[1] "x" "y"
```

Now if you loop through `ls()` you loop through the character vector and not through your actual workspace. (I use print instead of `View` to catch the output of the loop)

```
for(i in ls()){
  print(i)
}

[1] "x"
[1] "y"
```

You can fix this using `get`, but you need to use `lapply` as wit ha for-loop the output is overwritten in each iteration:

```
lapply(ls(), function(i) {
  View(get(i))
})
```

Or you use `mget(ls())` to first get the objects and than apply `View` to it:

```
lapply(mget(ls()), View)
```

Comment: Personally I would keep the for loop (or wrap the `lapply` into `invisible`) and use the second argument of `View` as @Andre did. To be "safer" about what will be displayed I might do some of the following: use `mode = "list"` inside of `mget`, test for the element being a data frame in the loop, use the `pattern` argument of `ls` to make sure I'm really opening a window for what I want only.

Comment: hi kath,
Thanks for the reply. Both of those worked. I also tried a variation of lapply prior to your comment which didn't work, I now understand why:  
`lapply(ls(), View)`

I can close this off now. Thankyou everyone for your replies :D

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 <- mtcars
df2 <- mtcars
df3 <- mtcars

lapply(ls(),function(x){View(get(x),x);NULL})
```

use the title argument of View to get meaningful title names.